# Get tooltip text from cheerio parsed html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, cheerio

[image]I am using cheerio to extract text node from the html file. 
can somebody please guide me if there is any way one can extract tooltip text using cheerio?  i.e.

scenario 1:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px;" uib-tooltip="this is tooltip text">
          this is text
</div>
```

scenario 2:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px;" uib-tooltip="this is inner tooltip text">
       <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px;" uib-tooltip="this is inner tooltip text">
          this is enclosed text
</div>
</div>
```

the attached screenshot shows the json object which cheerio provides on parsing html

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from your question is that you want innerHTML of an element which has `uib-tooltip` attribute.

So, you can just use `$('[uib-tooltip]').html()` to get the innerHTML, or any other selecter which suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

That's an attribute, therefore:

```
$('.row').attr('uib-tooltip')
```